why is my worksheet not showing up in excel using python pandas
i added 2 worksheets to my excel workbook and it was going fine, now i tried adding the third one, and no matter how much i try it doesnt seem to work, im using openpyxl library and pandas, this is the code after i ran it through blackbox

import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

# Load the CSV file into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('E:/test.csv')

# Filter the DataFrame to include only the required columns
required_columns = ["Last Updated Time", "Device", "Site", "Time Difference", "Device Type", "Last Alarm Received Time"]
filtered_df = df[required_columns]

# Fill blank cells in the "Last Alarm Received Time" column with "No Alarms"
filtered_df['Last Alarm Received Time'] = filtered_df['Last Alarm Received Time'].fillna('No Alarms')

# Filter the DataFrame for pivot_table1 based on the specified conditions
filter_values_pivot1 = [" second ago", " seconds ago", "minute ago", "minutes ago", "hour ago", " hours ago"]
filtered_df_pivot1 = filtered_df[~filtered_df["Last Alarm Received Time"].str.contains('|'.join(filter_values_pivot1))]

# Filter the DataFrame for pivot_table2 based on the specified conditions
# Define the filter values for pivot_table2
filter_values_pivot2 = ["0 s", "1 s", "2 s", "3 s"]

# Filter the DataFrame based on the condition for pivot_table2
filtered_df_pivot2 = filtered_df[~filtered_df["Time Difference"].isin(filter_values_pivot2)]

# Write the filtered DataFrame back to an Excel file
filtered_df_pivot1.to_excel('E:/filtered_test_pivot1.xlsx', index=False)
filtered_df_pivot2.to_excel('E:/filtered_test_pivot2.xlsx', index=False)

# Load the workbook and select the active worksheet
workbook = load_workbook('E:/filtered_test.xlsx')
worksheet1 = workbook.active

# Naming the first worksheet
worksheet1.title = "Devices with No Alarms > 24hrs"

# Create a new worksheet for the second PivotTable
worksheet2 = workbook.create_sheet(title="Devices with Time Difference > 3s")

# Create a new worksheet for the summary table
worksheet3 = workbook.create_sheet(title="Summary")

# Create PivotTable using pandas for the first worksheet
pivot_table1 = pd.pivot_table(filtered_df_pivot1, index=["Last Updated Time", "Device","Device Type", "Site", "Last Alarm Received Time"], aggfunc='count')

pivot_table1 = pivot_table1.drop('Time Difference', axis=1)

# Create PivotTable using pandas for the second worksheet
pivot_table2 = pd.pivot_table(filtered_df_pivot2, index=["Last Updated Time", "Device", "Device Type", "Site", "Time Difference"], aggfunc='count')
pivot_table2 = pivot_table2.drop('Last Alarm Received Time', axis=1)

# Save both PivotTables to separate sheets within the same Excel file
with pd.ExcelWriter('E:/filtered_test_with_pivot.xlsx') as writer:
    pivot_table1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Devices with No Alarms > 24hrs')
    pivot_table2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Devices with Time Difference > 3s')

# Define the data range for the first PivotTable
max_row = worksheet1.max_row
max_col= worksheet1.max_column
data_range1 = f"A1:{get_column_letter(max_col)}{max_row}"

# Set the data range for the first PivotTable
pivot_table1.location = 'A1'  
pivot_table1.table_range = data_range1

# Add fields to the first PivotTable
pivot_table1.pivot_field_axis('Last Updated Time', 'F')
pivot_table1.pivot_field_axis('Last Alarm Received Time', 'R')
pivot_table1.pivot_field_axis('Device', 'R')
pivot_table1.pivot_field_axis('Device Type', 'R')

# Add the PivotTable to the worksheet with top row as 1
worksheet1.add_pivot(pivot_table1, top_row=1)

# Define the data range for the second PivotTable
max_row = worksheet2.max_row
max_col = worksheet2.max_column
data_range2 = f"A1:{get_column_letter(max_col)}{max_row}"

# Set the data range for the second PivotTable
pivot_table2.location = 'A1'  # Change this to your desired location for the PivotTable
pivot_table2.table_range = data_range2

# Add fields to the second PivotTable
pivot_table2.pivot_field_axis('Last Updated Time', 'F')
pivot_table2.pivot_field_axis('Time Difference', 'R')
pivot_table2.pivot_field_axis('Device', 'R')
pivot_table2.pivot_field_axis('Device Type', 'R')

# Add the PivotTable to the worksheet with top row as 1
worksheet2.add_pivot(pivot_table2, top_row=1)

# Add a table to the summary worksheet
worksheet3.append([pd.Timestamp.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), len(df), len(filtered_df_pivot1), len(filtered_df_pivot2)])

# Define the data range for the summary table
max_row = worksheet3.max_row
max_col = worksheet3.max_column
data_range3 = f"A1:{get_column_letter(max_col)}{max_row}"

# Set the data range for the summary table
worksheet3.add_table(data_range3, table_style="TableStyleMedium9")

# Save the workbook with the PivotTables
workbook.save('E:/filtered_test_with_pivot.xlsx')

I tried running my code through various AIs, nothing worked, i tried to duplicate the worksheet that i previously added, but still nothing seems to be changing

do you get error or what? Or maybe you write on one file but you check different file.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Possibly due to having Sheet name(s) that are too long. Max number of characters should be less than 32; workbook.create_sheet(title="Devices with Time Difference > 3s") is a title of 33 characters.

sorry, this was a very ambiguous question, i was getting bunch of different error, ones regarding my filtering used in the first table, and another one thats regarding the character limit, i found a way to work it out, while still having these error show up in the terminal, so i dont think they were the reason why

what i did to solve the issue was reorder my code, so i made all tables at once, then made their designated worksheets and saved them to them afterwards,  thanks all !
